# LM13700 Question

Tags: filter, signal, trace

I'm currently troubleshooting a state-variable filter I built. All of the filter types work, but the resonance pot has no effect. Tracing a sine signal through the feedback pathway, I found that it ended at pin 7 of U6 - a LM13700. This is the input to the transistor buffers, and there's no audible signal coming out on pin 8, which is the output from that buffer.

[Here's the schematic](http://www.musicfromouterspace.com/analogsynth_new/STATEVARVCFFEB2006/STATEVARVCF_FEB06_PG2_schem.pdf)

[image]

I'm working from. I'm referring to U6. It looks like it is hooked up as an emitter follower. DC voltage at pin 7 is -36.7mV and at 8 is -252mV.

Should I be hearing the signal coming out pin 8?

Comment: We need more information to answer your question. For starters, what voltage and frequency sine wave are you putting in, and what gain do you expect? (If you could show us a schematic, that would increase the chances of you getting an answer by at least 10x.)

Answer (score 5):

The answer is, yes you should have signal at pin 8.  If you have signal at pin 7 and no signal at pin 8.  I would disconnect the output from everything but R57, to make sure it isn't loaded somewhere else.  If there is still no signal, I would disconnect R56 to leave the 5-7 connection unbiased to ground.  Better yet a trim pot at R56 and a trim pot at R57. Adjust till signal re-appears!

That load value(R57) looks low to me but I have only used LM13700's with single sided supplies appx. 9V so that might be why.

But definitely, signal at 7 should lead to signal at 8.

Comment: Thanks, you were right about looking at R57. Needed to change the value.

Comment: Score! That is why this site rocks!  Need help find help, have help give help!  How does that synth sound btw?

Comment: Sounds great. I'll probably post some video soon.

Answer (score 4):

If the output transistors are connected as an [emitter follower](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_collector), like in this circuit:

[image]

then yes, there should be a signal at pin 8.  What's the DC voltage at pins 7 and 8?  What else is connected to pin 8?  Where is the signal at pin 7 coming from?

Pins 9 and 10 do the same thing, did you compare with those?  Are they used as the other half of a stereo pair, or for some other function?

[image]

Comment: Thanks, here's the schematic I'm working from:

http://www.musicfromouterspace.com/analogsynth/STATEVARVCFFEB2006/STATEVARVCFFEB2006.html

I'm referring to U6, on the second page of the schematic. It looks like it is hooked up as an emitter follower. DC voltage at pin 7 is -36.7mV and at 8 is -252mV. Does that help at all?